# "Extending by linearity" - meaning?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, inner-products

In Sagan's book *The Symmetric Group*, he introduces the inner product on $\mathbb{C}\{\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2}, \mathbf{3}\}=\left\{c_1 \mathbf{1}+c_2 \mathbf{2}+c_3 \mathbf{3} \mid c_{1} c_{2}, c_{3} \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$ by
$$
\langle\mathbf{i}, \mathbf{j}\rangle=\delta_{i, j}
$$
for any two vectors in the basis $\{\mathbf{1},\mathbf{2},\mathbf{3}\}$. He then writes "*Now we extend by linearity in the first variable and conjugate linearity in the second to obtain an inner product on the whole vector space*". Can someone explain what "extend by linearity" means in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\{ \mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2}, \mathbf{3} \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C}\{ \mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2}, \mathbf{3}\}$, every vector $x \in \mathbb{C}\{ \mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2}, \mathbf{3}\}$ can be represented as $x = a \mathbf{1} + b \mathbf{2} + c \mathbf{3}$ for some coefficients $a, b, c \in \mathbb C$.
This expression is linear in the coefficients.

Because you know how a scalar product interacts with the linear structure, you can now deduce the value of the scalar products for any vectors in $\mathbb{C}\{ \mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2}, \mathbf{3}\}$, e.g.
$$
\langle a \mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2} \rangle = a \langle \mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2} \rangle, \qquad a \in \mathbb C
$$
or
$$
\langle \mathbf{1} + b \mathbf{3}, \mathbf{2} \rangle = \langle \mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2} \rangle + \overline{b}\langle \mathbf{3}, \mathbf{2} \rangle, \qquad b \in \mathbb C.
$$

Comment: So it means that if we take $\boldsymbol{v}=(a \mathbf{1}+b \mathbf{2}+c \mathbf{3})$ and $\boldsymbol{w}=(d \mathbf{1}+e \mathbf{2}+f \mathbf{3})$, then 'extending linearly' means that we define the inner product such that $\langle\boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{w}\rangle=a \bar{d}\langle\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{1}\rangle+a \bar{e}\langle\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2}\rangle+\cdots=a \bar{d}+b \bar{e}+c \bar{f}$?

Comment: @Logi That is correct.